# Receiving "SyntaxError" on simple function

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am working through the exercises in Bill Lubanovic's "Introducing Python" text ((C) 2015).  When I copy a simple program into the Python interpreter (Python 3.6.2), I receive a SyntaxError.

Here is the code:

```
def echo(anything):
    return anything ' ' anything
```

Here is the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    return anything ' ' anything
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lubanovic says his book was written and tested for Python 3.3.  Am I receiving this error because I am using version 3.6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "+".

```
def echo(anything):
    return anything + ' ' + 

echo('hello')
```

Output:

```
'hello hello'
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I am curious why the code I presented is printed in the book if it does not work.

Comment: @jdroth27 I found a copy of that book online, and that version did have the "+".  http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1508/Introducing%20Python.pdf Page 87

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Scott. I think I'll use this version instead. :) My copy was checked out from the library. I suppose it's possible that it included an erratum at one time.